# how to display blob type of image in struts2 from Mysql Db

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, blob

Blob type of image is reaching JSP page but it is in an unreadable format.

Service Method:

```
Iterator itr = list.iterator();
if (itr.hasNext()) {
     Membersdetails get = (Membersdetails) itr.next();
     repCurrentImage = get.getRepPicture();
}
return repCurrentImage;
```

& my Action Class:

```
repCurrentImage = sdf.getrepImage(loginId);
```

Finally My JSP page:

```
<img src="<s:property value="repCurrentImage"/>
```

Comment: How do u want to display the image. In a table or you want to render it on the page.

Comment: Storing files in database is bad design. I would suggest to store the `file-name` or `file-id` in database and pick the file from file-system only.

Comment: @tusar how so? The bench marks I've seen show marginal performance difference and it avoids some platform specific issues with how containers each manage file systems.

Comment: @ Uchenna I want to show it in  table tag using image tag

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to embed the content of the image directly into the JSP... this will not work you can only supply a url (best constructed with the struts2 url tag, which will reference the action which will return a stream result and take the required parameters to select your image).

This question/answer shows an action with such a result type which is used to render a picture: [How to display image(bolb type) in jsp page from mySql DB in Struts 2 using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330503/how-to-display-imagebolb-type-in-jsp-page-from-mysql-db-in-struts-2-using-hibe)

I'm my experience a good DB datatype is MEDIUMBLOB, with anything smaller truncation of the image became an issue (You will just see the first part of the file because that is all that can be stored although it would probably be best in production to make sure the file fits!).

Comment: +1 for the nice example link @Quaternion sir. And regarding my comments about bad design, I didn't think of cross-platform dependency. Thanks for clearing. Actually I have this perception that file-systems will always be faster than database while storing and retrieving files.

Comment: new code:    if (itr.hasNext())
             {
                Membersdetails get = (Membersdetails) itr.next();
                repCurrentSignature = get.getRepSignature();
             HttpServletResponse res = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                res.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
                ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
                out.write(repCurrentSignature);
                out.flush();
                
            }