# How to display image(bolb type) in jsp page from mySql DB in Struts 2 using Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, struts2

I am facing one problem, How to display image(bolb type) in jsp page from mySql DB in Struts 2 using Hibernate ?Please share your view.Thanks in advance.

```
    public byte[] getrepImagechange2(int loginid) {

    Criteria criteria = null;
    byte[] repCurrentImage = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        criteria = session.createCriteria(Membersdetails.class).add(Expression.eq("logintable.loginId", loginid));
        List list = criteria.list();
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        if (itr.hasNext()) {

            Membersdetails get = (Membersdetails) itr.next();
            repCurrentImage = get.getRepPicture();

            HttpServletResponse response23 = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
            response23.setContentType("image/jpg");
            OutputStream out = response23.getOutputStream();
            out.write(repCurrentImage);
            out.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in getrepImage() :" + e);
    } finally {
        try {

            session.flush();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getrepImage resource closing  :" + e);
        }
    }
    return repCurrentImage;
}
  And I am displaying this image in jsp page in a table cell using this code :                     
   <img src="<s:property value="bs"/>"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to render images from JPA (Hibernate Backed) example uses the struts2-conventions-plugin, in the result type annotation "stream" is all there is to the view:

```
package com.kenmcwilliams.photogallery.action.gallery;

import com.kenmcwilliams.photogallery.orm.Picture;
import com.kenmcwilliams.photogallery.orm.PictureDetails;
import com.kenmcwilliams.photogallery.service.Gallery;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Result(type = "stream", params = {
    "contentType", "${contentType}",
    "contentLength", "${contentLength}",
    "contentDisposition", "${contentDisposition}",
    "inputStream", "${inputName}",
    "bufferSize", "${bufferSize}",
    "allowCaching", "${allowCaching}"
})
public class Stream extends ActionSupport {
    @Autowired private Gallery gallery; 
    private String contentType = "text/plain";
    private int contentLength = 0;
    private String contentDisposition = "inline";
    private InputStream inputStream;
    public String inputName = "inputStream";//This should not be required
    private Integer bufferSize = 1024;
    private String allowCaching = "true";
    private Integer id = null;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        if (id != null){
            //gallery.get
            PictureDetails details = gallery.getPictureDetails(id);
            Picture photo = details.getPictureId();
            this.contentType = details.getContentType();
            System.out.println("Content Type: " + contentType);
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo.getPicture());
            this.contentLength = photo.getPicture().length;
            System.out.println("Content Length: " + contentLength);
            this.inputStream = byteArrayInputStream;
        }else{
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contentType
     */
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    /**
     * @param contentType the contentType to set
     */
    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contentLength
     */
    public int getContentLength() {
        return contentLength;
    }

    /**
     * @param contentLength the contentLength to set
     */
    public void setContentLength(int contentLength) {
        this.contentLength = contentLength;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contentDisposition
     */
    public String getContentDisposition() {
        return contentDisposition;
    }

    /**
     * @param contentDisposition the contentDisposition to set
     */
    public void setContentDisposition(String contentDisposition) {
        this.contentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bufferSize
     */
    public int getBufferSize() {
        return bufferSize;
    }

    /**
     * @return the allowCaching
     */
    public String getAllowCaching() {
        return allowCaching;
    }

    /**
     * @param allowCaching the allowCaching to set
     */
    public void setAllowCaching(String allowCaching) {
        this.allowCaching = allowCaching;
    }

    /**
     * @return the inputStream
     */
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    /**
     * @param inputStream the inputStream to set
     */
    public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

You also asked about how to display the above, the following is a JSP used to show a gallery of pictures (so the action will provide this JSP with image ids which the above action will use to get the pictures from the DB and the title of the Gallery).

If I remember correctly this gallery displays four pictures wide with as many rows as needed to show all the pictures.

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><s:property value="photoGallery.name"/></h1>
        <table>
            <s:iterator begin="0" end="pictureDetails.size/4" var="row">
                <tr>
                    <s:subset source="pictureDetails" start="4 * #row" count="4">
                        <s:iterator>
                            <s:url forceAddSchemeHostAndPort="true" namespace="/gallery" action="stream" var="streamURL">
                                <s:param name="id" value="id"/>
                            </s:url>
                            <td>
                                <s:a value="%{#streamURL}"><img width="200px" src="<s:property value="#streamURL"/>"/></s:a>
                            </td>
                        </s:iterator>
                    </s:subset>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above this line is probably this part is probably what you want:

```
<img width="200px" src="<s:property value="#streamURL"/>"/>
```

Comment: thks for your ans but i am not using annotaion ,i am simply storing image .but i am unable to dispaly on JSP page.

Comment: I don't work with Hibernate, but i can show your how to show image on your page if your have ImputStream with the image in your Action.

Comment: I am using  above code in my action class and using img tag  in jsp for displaying purpose

Comment: I blocked from stackoverfolw since 2 month. can anyone tell me how to activate question posting again? please help me.............................give me at least one chance again